# How do I make apex:inputField disabled Or readOnly

Tags: apex, disable

I have a parent account field with a magnifying glass on the right side of it. I need to users to only click on the magnifier glass and search for the parent and  not type in the field . Most of the time they spell it wrong and they wont click on the magnify glass and they get error.

```
 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!IF($UserRole.Name =='Channel Manager' || $UserRole.Name == 'Outside Sales Director' ||$UserRole.Name == 'Salesforce Administrator', true , false)}" >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Parent Account" for="acctparent" />
        <apex:inputField id="acctparent"  styleClass="acctparent" value="{!account.ParentId}"  />
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
```

I have tried javascript and didnt work

```
$("input[id*='acctParent']").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

or

```
$("input[id*='acctParent']").attr("disabled","true");
```

or

```
$("input[id*='acctParent']").prop('readonly', true);
```

i tired

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!onOff}">
<apex:inputField value="{!someField}"/>
```

didnt work

I tried

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution i guess I can use this

html-disabled="true"

```
<apex:inputField id="acctparent"  styleClass="acctparent" value="{!account.ParentId}"  html-disabled="true"  />
```

and as a secondary way if you have onchange on your button, use the following

```
onfocus="this.blur" onkeypress="this.blur()"  onchange="getSobjectList()"
```

Comment: If you would have read the comments your issue was simply a case sensitive issue. your jQuery would have worked had you used `acc` **p** `arent` with proper placement

Comment: the one on Mark Pond does not seem to work while html-disabled="true"  is definitely the answer !!..Thanks Meta

Comment: this answer is rather misleading. the `disabled` attribute is not a boolean. if you set `disabled="false"` it will still be disabled

Answer (score 5):

I think a better solution is to use `<apex:outputField>`.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputField.htm

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is case sensitive. `<apex:inputField id="acctparent"` has a lowercase p in the id value, your selector rule has an uppercase P. `$("input[id*='acctParent']")`

Correct that and you'll probably be in business.